# Cannot update contentDocumentId in contentDocumentLink

Tags: update, content, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink, sobjectexception

I am sharing a file with a task by creating `ContentDocumentLink`.

The `LinkedEntityId` points to the task record.

Now, if a certain update happens to a parent record then i am trying to update only `ContentDocumentId` in the `ContentDocumentLink` that was previously inserted.

However, i am getting an exception,

> execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.SObjectException: Field is
>   not writeable: ContentDocumentLink.ContentDocumentId

Do I need to delete previous `ContentDocumentLink` and insert a new `ContentDocumentLink` with updated `ContentDocumentId`?

Can't we update `ContentDocumentId` in `ContentDocumentLink` directly?

Answer (score 3):

**ContentDocumentId** is of type reference and Properties are **Create, Filter, Group, Sort**. It is ID of the document which have been linked with any record.

> Note:- Once you create a ContentDocumentLink, You can not update it.

If you are trying to change ContentDocumentId means you want to remove the current document shared with it and replace it with another document.

You must create another ContentDocumentLink with ContentDocumentId having your desired new document and LinkentityId with the record id of the record with which you want to share.

> Side Note:- Inserting a new document needs to insert using
>   ContentVersion Object as you cannot insert ContentDocument.

So, Your answer would be:-

1. Yes, you need to delete the previous ContentDocumentLink and insert a new ContentDocumentLink with updated ContentDocumentId
2. No, You can not update ContentDocumentId in ContentDocumentLink directly

Reference:-

- [ContentDocumentLink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm)
- [ContentDocument](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm?search_text=contentDocument)

Answer (score -1):

ContentDocumentId can only set while insert not for update. Alternative approach :

Step 1: Query the ContentDocumentLink record where  **LinkedEntityId = :ParentId**. In your case Task Id is the ParentId.

Step 2: Delete the ContentDocumentLink record in step 1.

Step 3: Recreate the ContentDocumentLink record again.